# elasticsearch : replace several term request in a should container by one unique request

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to make a request on an array of number in spite of repeat the same term request several time with a different searched term

This is my request with three differents term query in a should container

```
POST /test_index/film_type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "id_film": {
                    "value": 4
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "id_film": {
                    "value": 5
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "id_film": {
                    "value": 45
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Do you know how to do this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a look at the [Simple Query String Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html)

Small example:

```
POST test/test/1
{
  "film-id": 1
}

POST test/test/2
{
  "film-id": 2
}

POST test/test/3
{
  "film-id": 3
}


GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "1 | 2",
      "fields": [
          "film-id"
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

result:

```
"hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "film-id": 2
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "film-id": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!